# GraphQL How to read values with dealy using UseSubscription hook

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I have created a graphQL Realtime server and client reading values using useSubscription hook. Can anyone tell me please how to create a delay of few seconds to read the values.

Right now on the server side, I have created a change stream on a mongoDB collection and whenever an object is inserted into that collection it pushes the data to graphql subscription and the client receives it, The problem is the process which enters the data is inserting too many values in one second and i need just the most latest one and probably most latest with 5 seconds. So I need to create some sort of delay either on server side or client side.

Comment: server side definitely ... a kind of debouncing ... if you have a stream then you can use it in a functional way

Comment: i have used that technique with Angular and RxJs not sure how to create delays with react, even if server side, since i am monitoring MongoDb Change stream, wondering if that provides a feature, looking for a nice clean way to do this.